# NS3 Network Simulator with XG-PON module

Tags: ns-3

I am new in the field of networking. I am working on NS3 simulator, version 3.27. I downloaded it, build it and run the examples first.cc, second.cc etc (location: /home/user/ns-allinone-3.27/ns-3.27/examples/tutorial).

Now, I want to link the XG-PON module along with NS3. I downloaded the module from sourceforge.net. And copied the folder to the "src" folder in NS3. I tried building the simulator again using the command 
`./build.py --enable-examples --enable-tests`. But doing this gives the following error.

```
'configure' finished successfully (2.415s)
 =>  /usr/bin/python waf build
Waf: Entering directory `/home/divya/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/build'
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/divya/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/build'
source not found: 'test/xgpon-pool-allocation-test.cc' in bld(features=['cxx', 'cxxshlib', 'ns3module', 'ns3testlib'], ns3_dir_location='src/xgpon', pcfilegen=bld(features='ns3pcfile', idx=4, meths=[], prec=defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {}), _name='', source='', module='ns3-xgpon-test', mappings={}, path=/home/divya/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/src/xgpon, target='') in /home/divya/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/src/xgpon, use=['ns3-xgpon'], mappings={}, uselib='', meths=['_add_test_code', 'apply_bundle', 'process_rule', 'process_source', 'apply_link', 'apply_implib', 'process_use', 'propagate_uselib_vars', 'apply_incpaths_ns3testlib', 'apply_incpaths', 'apply_vnum', 'collect_compilation_db_tasks', 'install_boost', 'set_macosx_deployment_target'], prec=defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {}), source=['test/xgpon-pool-allocation-test.cc', 'test/xgpon-olt-dba-engine-giant-test.cc'], test=True, install_path='${LIBDIR}', module_deps=['xgpon'], dependencies=['xgpon'], path=/home/divya/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/src/xgpon, vnum=None, posted=True, is_static=False, target='../../ns3.26-xgpon-test-debug', idx=3, _name='ns3-xgpon-test', is_ns3_module_test_library=True, module_name='ns3-xgpon') in /home/divya/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/src/xgpon
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build.py", line 171, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "./build.py", line 162, in main
    build_ns3(config, build_examples, build_tests, args, build_options)
  File "./build.py", line 82, in build_ns3
    run_command([sys.executable, "waf", "build"] + build_options)
  File "/home/divya/ns-allinone-3.26/util.py", line 25, in run_command
    raise CommandError("Command %r exited with code %i" % (argv, retval))
util.CommandError: Command ['/usr/bin/python', 'waf', 'build'] exited with code 1
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked if the module is compatible with the version of NS-3 you're running? For e.g you mention ns-3.27 in the description but the system looks in the ns-3.26 directory according to the log.

Answer (score 0):

The Waf build tool is complaining that it cannot find one of the source files (test/xgpon-pool-allocation-test.cc) that is listed in the wscript for the xgpon module.  The solution is to either remove this file from the list of buildable test files in the wscript, or find out why it is missing and insert it into the test directory.